# Group by crosstab in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do something rather simple in R (I think) but cannot figure out how. One of the nice things that SPSS can do for me is quick table of a summary statistic (ie average) by a categorical variable.

So I have a category within my dataframe calle TC Code and a numeric variable called AMT. All I want is the average AMT by TC code

```
TC Code    AMT Ave
A          $ Ave value
B          $ Average Value
etc
```

I keep trying to do something with the CrossTable function by no luck.

Comment: This is trivial in R, and examples for how to do it literally abound on the web. See `aggregate` or `by` or `ddply` (**plyr** package), among many options.

Comment: There's also `tapply`.

Comment: Maybe I am getting closer. Using the aggregate code as listed in answer 1.   aggregate(res, 'FAC_AMT' ~ 'TC Code', mean). But getting error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(res, "FAC_AMT" ~ "TC Code", mean) : 
  'by' must be a list

Comment: Also tried: aggdata <-aggregate(res, by=list('FAC_AMT','TC Code'),
                    FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE). But getting error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(res, by = list("FAC_AMT", "TC Code"), FUN = mean,  : 
  arguments must have same length

Comment: [please watch video #029](http://www.twotorials.com/) and maybe the 28 before it as well ;)

Comment: That helped. A problem I was having was also with the dataset. I fixed that, then #29 did great. thanks

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, is that what they call a "crash course"??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide *reproducible code* (generate some data and explain what you require).

Some data:

```
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(code = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 
           50, replace=TRUE), val = sample(50))
```

Using `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(data = df, val ~ code, mean)
  code      val
1    A 19.33333
2    B 26.00000
3    C 27.72727
4    D 21.50000
5    E 29.66667
6    F 30.20000
7    G 13.00000
8    H 24.50000
```